# Multiple KEY_PRESSED events for single key press (equals '=' key)

Tags: java, macos, swing, java-7, keylistener

I am seeing this in OS X using Java 7 (update 67) when I type Command-equals (⌘=).  Here is an example:

```
public class Test implements KeyEventDispatcher {

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new Test());
    }



    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
        System.out.println(ke);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The output I see for ⌘=.  Note, the three KEY_PRESSED events, all for =, with no KEY_RELEASED event for =.  Also note that the second one indicates a keyChar of + as well as the complete lack of KEY_TYPED events.

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=157,keyText=⌘,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=⌘,extModifiers=⌘,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=61,keyText==,keyChar='=',modifiers=⌘,extModifiers=⌘,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=61,keyText==,keyChar='+',modifiers=⌘,extModifiers=⌘,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=61,keyText==,keyChar='=',modifiers=⌘,extModifiers=⌘,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=157,keyText=⌘,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on frame0
```

The multiple events do propagate to the listener or binding or menu accelerator, which is how I originally discovered the issue.

For comparison, here's the output for ⌘-.  No multiple events, but still no KEY_TYPED events either.

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=157,keyText=⌘,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=⌘,extModifiers=⌘,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=45,keyText=-,keyChar='-',modifiers=⌘,extModifiers=⌘,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=157,keyText=⌘,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0,extendedKeyCode=0x0] on frame0
```

Finally, here's the output for ⌘= in Java 6:

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=157,keyText=⌘,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=⌘,extModifiers=⌘,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=61,keyText==,keyChar='=',modifiers=⌘,extModifiers=⌘,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x0,keyChar='=',modifiers=⌘,extModifiers=⌘,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=61,keyText==,keyChar='=',modifiers=⌘,extModifiers=⌘,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0] on frame0
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=157,keyText=⌘,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=0,scancode=0] on frame0
```

I haven't been able to find any bug reports related to this.  Is there any explanation for this?  As a workaround, all I can think of to do it ignore these multiple events based on timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant bug report on Oracle's web site is [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8020209).

The cause of this bug is MacOS itself. I just tried in plain non-Java applications (Firefox and Terminal) to press ⌘=, and I get the zoom action, which should be activated by ⌘+. Note that one of the events in your list has a keyChar of "+" rather than "=".

I suppose that Apple did this because many more applications use ⌘+ than ⌘=, and they didn't want to force the user to click ⌘⇧= instead. So they did a series of events and let the application handle it. But that's entirely a surmise on my part.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  It appears a timestamp based workaround is the only solution for now.